# Different assignment of base address to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am referring a book Named "Let Us c" By Yashwant Kanetkar.
I am a little confused about this example where he assigns a base address to a pointer.
Example:

```
int x[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};  
int *p = x; // base address of x assigned to *p  
//************// 
int z[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
int *q = &z[0]; // base address of z assigned to *q
```

If both have the same functionality then why is different notation used? Is there any other reason for doing this?

Comment: Just synonyms. But in the second case, you can do `int *q = &z[1]`, for example.

Comment: Take a free advice: Throw  that book if you really interested to learn C!!

Comment: `&*z` is also equivalent.

Comment: p = x + 0 doesn't bother you?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the name of an array in an assignment, like in the first case, the array decays to a pointer to the address of the first element.

In the second case, the expression `z[0]` gives you the first element of the array by value and when you prepend an ampersand `&` to the expression, you get the address of that element which renders the same result of the first case.

Comment: This thing i had already mentioned in my question. is there any other difference or it is just a way represent in different way

Comment: @Co.Aden no other difference, and I would say two different ways of getting the address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> Both are effectively same. By using the base index, you can iterate through the memory allocated for the array. In this case accessing a[10]; is not correct since array was defined to hold maximum of 10 elements.
>   The second notation is mostly used to assign the address of the particular element,, &x[n]

Answer (score -1):

The two different notations for the same result illustrate that `x`, the array, is truly just a pointer while `x[0]`, an element, is an actual value. This is just one of the many examples of multiple ways of saying the same thing in C (kind of like English).

Comment: -1. Arrays are not pointers. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @Keith Thompson, x contains a pointer to an array, isn't int?

Comment: @someuser x by itself will decay to a pointer to the first element (index 0) of the array and can be used somewhat like a pointer (e.g. x + 1 points to the second element of the array), but x itself is not a pointer. For example, `x = NULL;` or anything modifying x itself won't work because x is an array not a pointer. I'd say you can think of it as a const-qualified pointer (`int *const`), but that isn't technically true either because `sizeof x != sizeof &x[0]`, though it is logical when you think about it: how can you expect the size of 10 items to be the size of a pointer to one item?

Comment: See the link Keith posted for more information, but basically it boils down to arrays can be used like pointers so long as the so-called pointer itself is not modified. Btw, this also goes for pointers treated as arrays, especially when using malloc et al. since the actual data type is still a pointer, not an array. In other words, "arrays are not pointers", and "pointers are not arrays".